# how can i count number of columns in table

Tags: python, sql

i tried count number of columns in table ( access database) by python
but i had the previous error
[image]

```
#connector is the module file for connect to database 

import os
import pyodbc
class Connect():
# connect to database
    dataFile = "youssri_knowledge_v1.accdb"
    databaseFile  = os.getcwd() + "\\" + dataFile
    connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=%s" % databaseFile
    dbConnection   = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from tinformation")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

# fro test the connection
    #for row in rows:
        #print (row)
# select number of columns
    tinfo_col_number= cursor.execute ("select (*) from tinofrmation")
    print (tinfo_col_number)
```

Comment: Could you please post the error as text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I think you should use `COUNT()` function of sql :  https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution but in this way if you need know the number of rows/columns and the content you don't need query the DB twice;
when you do

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

you already have an list of list, where every your sub-list is a line of the DB so if you want the number of the row you can do:

```
len(rows)
```

if you want the number of the column you can just select one row and count how many element there are.... even if some row doesn't have all the element it will be reported with null values so:

```
len(rows[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could change query, MSSQL has a little diffrent syntax than MySQL.
Try this:

```
 tinfo_col_number= cursor.execute ("SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'tinofrmation'")
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.